# Can't get Access Token for Facebook SDK 4.8.1 for Android (OR) FacebookCallback is not called (OR) requestCode is different in Facebook integration

Tags: android, integration, access-token, facebook-access-token, android-facebook

I followed [Facebook login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) to integrate FB to my Android app. It is done. I see the permission screen where user has to accepet to use his email ID. Issue is that none of the callbacks of FacebookCallback are getting called.

I followed the same procedure mentioned in the above tutorial.

- I initiated FB SDK.
- Then created CallBackManager instance.
- Have setFragment(this).
- Registered FacebookCallback callabck this way

Fragment code:

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }  

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                mButtonFbLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
            mButtonFbLogin.setFragment(this);

            mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            mButtonFbLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FB Login Successful. Token : " +loginResult.getAccessToken());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FB Login cancelled..");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FB Login failed. Exception : " +e.toString());
                }
            });
       }   

       @Override
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult of Fragment..");
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

}
```

- Finally I called `mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`. My activity's onActivityResult() is called first from where I called fragment's onActivityResult().

Through logs, I see that `onActivityResult` of my fragment is called and so `onActivityResult()` of callbackManger too. But none of the callbacks of Facebook Callback are called.

Any clue ?

`AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` is a way which can be used in `onCreate()`. But with this I can not exactly know when first time the token is created.

And `AccessTokenTracker` is actually to track the changes in tokens but not to know when the login session is success, fail or cancelled.

**UPDATE:**

I just tried with AccessTokenTracker but onCurrentAccessTokenChanged() was not called after I pressed OK on permission screen and control is back to my fragment. This is the code:

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

```
mAccessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
            AccessToken oldAccessToken,
            AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCurrentAccessTokenChanged : old : " +oldAccessToken);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCurrentAccessTokenChanged : new : " +currentAccessToken);
    }
};
mAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

}

Comment: post your activity and fragment codes please

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa, added fragment's code. No code I have in Activity but I called onActivityResult() of my fragment from my Activity. That is all in Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had MainActivity which holds MainFragment which spawns CHildFragment. ChildFragment is where the LoginButton was added.

MainActivity -> MainFragment -> ChildFragment (LoginButton).

I had onActivityResult() in MainActivity and ChildFragment too. In onActivityResult() of MainActivity, I explicitly called childFragment.onActivityResult() where I called CallbackManager.onActivityResult(). I did setFragment(this) in ChildFragment. All fine but none of the callbacks in FacebookCallback were getting called.

I tried multiple solutions and debugged Facebook code too and found that the requestCode they use as index to store callback we sent. This code was different while storing the callback and while retrieving it. So nothing happened.

Part of debuggin, I moved the complete code to MainFragment and it worked. :-)

So, **solution** was to override onActivityResult() in MainFragment and called onActivityResult() of ChildFragment from there. IT WORKED.

So, the **conclusion** is that if you put LoginButton in child/nested fragment, Facebook sdk will call the onActivityResult of parent fragment but not the onActivityResult() of child fragment or Activity.

Comment: the only reason facebook does that because an activity context is passed via the fragment to the facebookSDK. The facebook SDK uses that context to call the callback